# Form Validation (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple form validation. It's working alright. The thing is I want my code to be optimized. Can somebody show me some pointers to improve my code? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.submit').click(function(){
     validateForm();     
});


function validateForm(){
    var nameReg = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var numberReg =  /^[0-9]+$/;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var names = $('#nameInput').val();
    var company = $('#companyInput').val();
    var email = $('#emailInput').val();
    var telephone = $('#telInput').val();
    var message = $('#messageInput').val();

    var inputVal = new Array(names, company, email, telephone, message);

    var inputMessage = ["name", "company", "email address", "telephone number", "message"];

    var textId = ["#nameLabel", "#companyLabel", "#emailLabel", "#telephoneLabel", "#messageInput"];

     $('.error').hide();

        if($.trim(inputVal[0]) === ""){
            $('#nameLabel').after('<span class="error"> Please enter your ' + inputMessage[0] + '</span>');

        }else if(!nameReg.test(names)){
            $('#nameLabel').after('<span class="error"> Letters only</span>');
        }

        if($.trim(inputVal[1]) === ""){
            $('#companyLabel').after('<span class="error"> Please enter your ' + inputMessage[1] + '</span>');
        }

        if($.trim(inputVal[2]) === ""){
            $('#emailLabel').after('<span class="error"> Please enter your ' + inputMessage[2] + '</span>');

        }else if(!emailReg.test(email)){
            $('#emailLabel').after('<span class="error"> Please enter a valid email address</span>');
        }

        if($.trim(inputVal[3]) === ""){
            $('#telephoneLabel').after('<span class="error"> Please enter your ' + inputMessage[3] + '</span>');

        }else if(!numberReg.test(telephone)){
            $('#telephoneLabel').after('<span class="error"> Numbers only</span>');
        }

        if($.trim(inputVal[4]) === ""){
            $('#messageLabel').after('<span class="error"> Please enter your ' + inputMessage[4] + '</span>');
        }   



    return false;

}   



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a for loop to test all values first. If one is invalid you can stop and fix before going on with the code or submitting. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3dGe/1/) without the submit callback so you can see how this would work.

The following code is explained in the comments.

```
(function($) { //Wrap your function in an IIFE. Assign "$" to jQuery to avoid conflicts with other libraries.
    $('#myform').submit(function() { //Form can be submitted without a "click"
        //You only need to say "var" once. After that just use "," and bump to the next one.
        var names = "       ", //I set this one empty to show you how it works
            company = "           good",
            email = "dat shi cra";

        var inputVal = [names, company, email],
            inputMessage = ["name", "company", "email address"],
            textId = ["#nameLabel", "#companyLabel", "#emailLabel"];


        for(var i=0;i<inputVal.length;i++){
            //We want to trim before the testing.
            //$.trim doesn't cut white space within the string.
            //ie: "     good" will return "good", but "goo    d" will return "goo    d".
            inputVal[i] = $.trim(inputVal[i]);

            //Here is where we test for invalid entries.
            //Is the value undefined? Is it null? Or is it an empty string? If any of these, it is invalid.
            //You can add more tests if you like.
            if (typeof inputVal[i] === 'undefined' || inputVal[i] === null || inputVal[i] === "") {
                // "i" will tell you which position is invalid.
                // Call the function and tell it which one is invalid.
                invalidEntry(i);

                //Stop at the first invalid we find.
                //If you want to collect all the invalids, remove the return, make an array, and push the "i" to it, then do something with the array.
                //When the loop is done that array will contain all the invalid entries numbered accordingly.
                return false;
            }
            //This will run for EACH VALID entry.
            console.log("Yolo bitcholo! So far so good!");
        };

        function invalidEntry(i) {
            //Get the index of the invalid and do your stuff.
            $(textId[i]).after("<span class='error'>Please enter a valid " + inputMessage[i] + ".</span>");
        }

        return this.some_variable //Only submit if this variable is set. This can contain your form data, which we would only want to submit if there is data to submit.
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, you shouldn't use `$('.submit').click()` but `$('#myForm').submit()` as you will be able to submit forms by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> too.
- To check if a string is a number, use `!isNan(string)` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175787/1149495) for more information).
- Email regex are difficult things. Just check if there is someting before the `@` (with `.+?`) and if there is something after the `@` (again with `.+?`) and if that last part contains a `.` and a couple of characters (from 2 to 6)
- It would make the function a lot easier if you put all specific code outside it. E.g:

```javascript
    validateForm({
        '#nameInput': {
            'valid': function (value) {
                return /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
            },
            'label': '#nameLabel',
            'messages': {
                'empty': 'Please enter your name',
                'invalid': 'Letters only',
            },
        },
        '#companyInput': {
            'label': '#companyLabel',
            'messages': {
                'empty': 'Please enter your company',
            },
        },
        // ...
    });
```